# Static Files or Images (PNG) doesn't load using C# NET 6 with React.js

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 net 6.0 for create a react project.
I used the ASP.Net Core with React.JS template

[Visual Studo 2022 Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpNh7.png)

I'm following this tutorial for create a new react application:
https://youtu.be/uii_TmfCjiM

My problem is the part Minute 22:00 of the video.
Where he add a validation in react for add a static file (And PNG image) to be specific.
In the project folder, there is an folder images, and I want to add one of these to a react component.
The idea is to load the image dynamically, using a call to the SQL DB to create the full path

My only difference between my current work space and the video, is I don't have separate projects for the react app and Visual studio Web API.
I used instead the "ASP.Net Core with React.JS" template I mention before.

I follow the tutorial and I add this code to the program.cs file:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Images")),
    RequestPath = "/Images"
});
```

And even did a extra config as well and in the setupProxy.js file, I add the images path to the context:

```
const context =  [
    "/api/Participants",
    "/api/Questions",
    "/Images"
];

module.exports = function(app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

But I'm still having issues when I try to load the image, this is how it looks like:
[Web Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U6BK.png)

And in the network tab in the DevTools I have this as an Status:
[Dev Tools network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXBzt.png)

Any ideas of what could be the problem.
Or what step I'm missing

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All after make my search this is the solution I found.
Using the documentation for the http-proxy-middleware, I found in this link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware

I found the answer for configure the proxy correctly for allow static files.

1. the program.cs file in .net 6 was correct and these were necessary for allow access the image folder:

   ```
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new 
        PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, 
        "Images")),
        RequestPath = "/Images"
    });
   ```

2. The lines I had to modify in the proxy was the context values.
   Noted I had to add the wild card "**" for allow all strings in the context, because you cannot combine string and wildcards. At the end the setupProxy.js :

   ```
    const context =["/api/Participants/**","/api/Questions/**","/images/**"];
    module.exports = function(app) {
    const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context,{
        target: target,secure: false,headers: {
            Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
        }
    });
    app.use(appProxy);
    };
   ```

As you can notice the wild card "*" for all the string path in the context array. Beside you can use this kind of wild card for allow an especific extension, like .png:

```
"/images/* *.png"
```